# Replacing IIS6 ssl cert with new one without downtime

Tags: iis, ssl, iis-6, ssl-certificate

I found this [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/30440/replace-old-ssl-certificate-in-iis6) and it sounds like my solution, but on my IIS server the "Replace the current certificate" option is grayed out. I can't go the route of doing a standard replace because the current SSL cert is from Verisign and the new one will be from Godaddy. Will this ungray itself once I import the new cert into the temporary site?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the Replace option will be available once there is another certificate installed on the system.